# css nav - css triangles

Tags: css, sass

[image: Trying to create this]

and need some help

Here is the state of things at the moment (i've removed the responsive part)

[State now](http://jsfiddle.net/pvdVn/3/)

basically i'm stuck on how to create the dropdown triangle,so that it works, and is centered.
- the nav is coming out of a cms, so i cannot be sure of exact dimensions(widths) of the navigation points

Basically i seem to be having a brain meltdown and need help !

ps - the css is coming from compass / sass using skelton

Comment: Position the element for the triangle so that it is horizontally centered below the object and vertically positioned so the triangle overlaps.  Then do the border/width modifications to get the top border creating the triangle you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangles can now be handled with pseudo classes.

Have a look at this fiddle for an idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/carlosmartinezt/PwEyq/

However, in your case you also need borders in the triangle which makes it harder. I think the quickest solution would be to use images instead.

Comment: hmmmm i've kicked out my borders, and edited my jsfiddle, but somehow still no triangle.

Obviously something is still wrong, but i can't spot it.

Edited [link]http://jsfiddle.net/carlosmartinezt/PwEyq/

Answer (score 0):

ok got it working with the following - have updated my jsfiddle

```
.keith > li:hover {
  position: relative; background: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #005381;
  color:#005381;
  z-index: 100000;
}
.keith > li:hover:after, .keith > li:hover:before {
  top: 100%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position:   absolute; pointer-events: none;
}
.keith > li:hover:after { border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border-top-color: #ffffff; 
border-width: 10px; left: 50%; margin-left: -10px; }
.keith > li:hover:before { border-color: rgba(0, 83, 129, 0); 
border-top-color: #005381; border-width: 11px; left: 50%; margin-left: -11px; }
```